# Modify underlying Go sub dependency on the package I am using

Tags: go, open-telemetry, cert-manager

I am getting this error from `go mod tidy` when I am trying to update my dependancies. I am primarily developing a webhook service to use with cert-manager and I cannot figure out how to resolve this dependency isssue since the packages I am dependent on are created by other developers and I cannot control those "sub dependency".

This is my output:

*go.opentelemetry.io/otel/semconv: module go.opentelemetry.io/otel@latest found (v1.9.0), but does not contain package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/semconv*

I looked the package up here: [https://pkg.go.dev/go.opentelemetry.io/otel/semconv](https://pkg.go.dev/go.opentelemetry.io/otel/semconv#section-directories)

and the problem for me seems like that the package have been restructured like this:

go.opentelemetry.io/otel/semconv/v1.9.0

as a subdirectory instead of package version.

Is there a way I can manipulate the underlying dependancy of the packages that my service is depending on?

Please leave a comment if you need addictional information.

Take a look at the accepted solution's comments

Comment: ```go clean -cache -modcache -i -r```

```https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/go-ot```

Comment: You can use the the `replace` directive to replace a specific dependency if needed.

Comment: I tried these but it did not resolve my issue. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use a local copy of the module where you can fix the issue and use it. Steps for that

1. Clone the module repository git clone https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-go.git
2. If needed, checkout to a branch/tag git checkout branch_name
3. In the go.mod file of your module, add the following lines

```
replace (
    go.opentelemetry.io => /path/where/cloned/opentelemetry-go
)
```

4. Now you should be able to modify code in the cloned `opentelemetry-go` repo and use it in your module

Comment: I am trying this solution but getting a `malformed module path "/Users/aaa/bbb/Repositories/opentelemetry-go": empty path element` and I did not found an solution to resolve this.

Comment: I managed to resolve the dependancy issue with your solution but I got lot of errors now that I dont even know and maybe too complex to fix. So I wrote to cert-manager dev intead but thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it is actually the solution for the problem but it is a bit harder more complex than that since turns out cert-manager uses plenty of diferrent versions of dependancies. If you find this question later and have the same issue I suggest you visit [link](https://github.com/topics/cert-manager-webhook)(cert-manager-webhook) topic on github and examine some recently updated implementations. :)

Comment: For me this replace() was not enought. See the https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-go/tree/main/example/jaeger, adapt all the redirects(and the require() modules) like they are shown in the go.mod, then it works.